# Next.JS Abort fetching component for route: "/login"

Tags: authentication, next.js, next-router

I was developing a useUser Hook for per-page authentication. I have implemented the useUser hook normally and Redirecting works fine accordingly.
But I am getting the above error.

> Abort fetching component for route: "/login"

How can I fix useUserHook to solve it??

```
//useUser.tsx
const useUser = ({ redirectTo, redirectIfFound }: IParams) => {
  const { data, error } = useRequest("authed", isAuthed);

  const user = data?.data;
  const hasUser = user;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!redirectTo) return;
    if (
      // If redirectTo is set, redirect if the user was not found.
      (redirectTo && !redirectIfFound && !hasUser) ||
      // If redirectIfFound is also set, redirect if the user was found
      (redirectIfFound && hasUser)
    ) {
      Router.push(redirectTo);
    }
  }, [redirectTo, redirectIfFound, hasUser]);

  return error ? null : user;
};
```

```
//index.tsx
const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const user = useUser({ redirectTo: "/login" });

  if (user === undefined || user === false) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <div>Home</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

UseRequest Hook returns true and false as return values.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### tl;dr

Ensure that you only call `router.push()` once throughout all potential re-executions of `useEffect` with the help of state:

```js
const [calledPush, setCalledPush] = useState(false); // <- add this state

// rest of your code [...]

 useEffect(() => {
    if (!redirectTo) return;
    if (
      (redirectTo && !redirectIfFound && !hasUser) ||
      (redirectIfFound && hasUser)
    ) {
        // check if we have previously called router.push() before redirecting
      if (calledPush) {
        return; // no need to call router.push() again
      }

      Router.push(redirectTo);
      setCalledPush(true); // <-- toggle 'true' after first redirect
    }
  }, [redirectTo, redirectIfFound, hasUser]);

  return error ? null : user;
};
```

### Background

`useEffect` potentially gets called multiple times if you have more than one dependency (Also happens with [React Strict Mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) enabled, but in this case there seems to be no error), and (re-)calling `router.push()` multiple times within the same Next.js page in different places/throughout different re-renders seems to cause this error in some cases, as the redundant `router.push()` call(s) will have to be aborted, because the current page-component unmounts due to the successful, previously called `router.push()`.

If we keep track of whether we have already called `router.push` via the `calledPush` state as in the code snippet above, we omit all redundant `router.push()` calls in potential `useEffect` re-executions, because for all subsequent `useEffect` executions the state value `calledPush` will already be updated to `true` as `useEffect` gets triggered after re-renders, hence after `setCalledPush(true)` takes effect.

Answer (score 5):

I also encountered a similar problem. An error will be reported when the network is slow or the `push` event is triggered multiple times in a short period.

I solved it like this:

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useSafePush = () => {
  const [onChanging, setOnChanging] = useState(false);
  const handleRouteChange = () => {
    setOnChanging(false);
  };
  const router = useRouter();
  // safePush is used to avoid route pushing errors when users click multiple times or when the network is slow:  "Error: Abort fetching component for route"
  const safePush = (path: string) => {
    if (onChanging) {
      return;
    }
    setOnChanging(true);
    router.push(path);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange);

    return () => {
      router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange);
    };
  }, [router, setOnChanging]);
  return { safePush };
};

export default useSafePush;
```

I observe the routeChangeComplete event, only when the route change is complete, the push function will be called.

usage:

```js
  const { safePush } = useRouterChange();
  safePush(path)
```

Comment: This is a really good solution! I made three tweaks:
1) wrapping `safePush` in `useCallback` to avoid triggering `useEffects` unnecessarily. 2) Support all argument options from `router.push` instead of just a string. 3) Return if `router.isReady === false`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have use rotuer.push("/") two times in a single file. That caused the error. Try using one. I think problem will be solved.

[image]

Comment: you shouldn't use side effects inside render body – move call `router.push` inside `useEffect`

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because `useEffect` tries to update a component that has already been unmounted and this can introduce memory leaks in which your app uses more memory than it needs to. To prevent this, use the following approach:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
  //first manually mount the effect
   let mounted = true;

  //check if component is currently mounted
   if(mounted && ...code){
     router.push('/index')
     }
  //cleanup side effects before unmounting
    return()=>{mounted=false}
  }, [router]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
You only have to stop the rerendering due to useEffect remove unnecessary dependencies will solve mine issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

In my current NextJS project, when I make `reactStrictMode: false,`, the value to false, then it seems like the re-rendering will be gone, and component will be only rendered once.

I don't like react strict mode very much ..