# Why do I get "Error: Abort fetching component for route: "/settings"" in next js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

this is my next js index file. Here i have used next-auth version 4 library.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react'
import { Login } from '@/components/Login/Login'

export default function Home() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const callbackUrl = (router.query?.callbackUrl as string) ?? '/dashboard'
  const { data: session, status } = useSession()

  const loading = status === 'loading'
  if (!loading && !session) {
   return <Login />
  }
  if (session) {
   router.push(callbackUrl)
  }
}
```

I have passed a custom login page for the sigin. It was achieved by setting the page inside [...nextauth].ts file

```
pages: {
  signIn: '/'
}
```

Above custom login page contain below button with an onclick event for the sign in.

```
<Button
  onClick={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    signIn('cognito', { redirect: false })
  }}
  appearance={appearance}
  style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}
>
```

But after the sign in, it's correctly redirected to the requested page, but there is an error in the console:

```
Error: Abort fetching component for route: "/settings"
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> Abort fetching component for route

This happens when calling `router.push()` from the main rendering flow as you are doing here :

```js
if (session) {
  router.push(callbackUrl)
}
```

I see you are trying to check if the session is loading but this is not the right approach to do so

What you need to do is create a wrapper component that handles session loading and decides whether to return its children or a custom component (loading) while the session is loading.

Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75428838/13488990) where this is explained in detail.

Answer (score 0):

it's because router.push() runs multiple times before it finishes loading the earlier router.push(). I think below is a better answer. it has some worked out solutions.

Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75872313/21563418) where this is explained in detail.